# R plot coreness layout

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, spiral

I've tried to draw a spiral plot for my data.
Here is my igraph network:
https://bulut.omu.edu.tr/index.php/s/WoSFKhMV7Rxtgem

So far, I've created this script which creates a circle plot. My problem is that the color of node should change according k-core. It means that outside of circle should be lighter and the center should be darker!:

```
# Load Library
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)
# Classic palette for red, with 5 colors
coul01 = brewer.pal(5, "RdPu") 
# I can add more tones to this palette :
coul01 = colorRampPalette(coul01)(60)
# Load igraph object
g <- readRDS("~g.rds")
# Plot coreness
CorenessLayout <- function(g) {
  coreness <- V(g)$kCore;#graph.coreness(g);
  xy <- array(NA, dim=c(length(coreness), 2));

  shells <- sort(unique(coreness));
  for(shell in shells) {
    v <- 1 - ((shell-1) / max(shells));
    nodes_in_shell <- sum(coreness==shell);
    angles <- seq(0,360,(360/nodes_in_shell));
    angles <- angles[-length(angles)]; # remove last element
    xy[coreness==shell, 1] <- sin(angles) * v;
    xy[coreness==shell, 2] <- cos(angles) * v;
  }
  return(xy);
}

# create layout
ll <- CorenessLayout(g);
# plot
plot(g, layout=ll, vertex.size=1, vertex.color=coul01,
     edge.width=.001,edge.arrow.size=.001,vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.frame.color=coul01)
```

[image: Color Problem]

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

PS: If you couldn't see the end result, please use this link
https://bulut.omu.edu.tr/index.php/s/sQpxqIOH04x9wtW

Comment: The example and the data provided are quite far from each other. Also it is not obvious to figure out the expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding @Heikki and you're right about data structure. I've tried to make necessary change for it. Thanks. PS: I added the example of final version.

Comment: Maybe you need to check the documentation on [radial_trans](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggforce/versions/0.1.1/topics/radial_trans)? Now it seems like your `r.range` is always zero `c(0,0)`.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question many times, and upvote the comments which helped you forward.

Comment: Hi @Heikki , I rephrased the question!

Comment: In stead of giving color palette as `vertex.color`, could you create a vector where you specify the color of each individual point in the plot? Then you would not have cyclic colors but colors set individually to each point.

Comment: I think that I found how to do it ;) my_color=coul[as.numeric(as.factor(V(network)$carac))] @Heikki Thanks